# Trouble Connecting to RDS PostgresQL SSL in Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl

I'm trying to setup my Laravel app in Docker to connect to a Postgresql database hosted on AWS RDS using SSL. In my config, I have the address of the certificate:

```
'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE', 'verify-full'),
'sslrootcert' => env('DB_SSLROOTCERT', '/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem')
```

I don't have anything overriding this in my .env file. I am able to connect to the server using psql:

```
psql -h {address} -p 5432 "dbname={dbname} user={user} sslrootcert=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/rds-combined-ca-bundle-root.pem sslmode=verify-full"
```

So I believe that I have the key setup properly. I get this error from Laravel:

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] root certificate file "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem" does not exist Either provide the file or change sslmode to disable server certificate verification
```

And you better believe that file exists. Anyone have any ideas of things that I can try?

Thanks!

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had AWS set to accept both the 2015 and 2019 keys, and I just needed it to accept the 2019 key.